# Incomplete info printing Exception.printStackTrace

Tags: java, android, exception, android-ksoap2, android-xmlpullparser

I am developing an Android app that uses ksoap2 library to interact with a web application through it's webservices. I've already succeeded creating some of these interactions. Now I am trying to use a webservice that gets lots of parameters and I didn't succeed with this one, for now. It throws me XMLPullParserException: unresolved.

I need to know what is going on to fix it. I get the exception in Logcat using this code:

```
try {
    // The code that makes the XML request to the webservice.
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

THE PROBLEM is that the resulting log interleaves the message returned by the server, so I can't see the detailed information about what's wrong with my XML request's structure:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unresolved: &eacute;
(position:TEXT Some server messag...@1:40 in java.io.InputStreamReader@405dc958)
```

**How can I get the complete error message returned by the server?** I've used some of the methods found in this documentation and they didn't give me the server message:

[Throwable | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Throwable.html)

[StackTraceElement | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html)